# Boot Camp Assistant: "This Mac does not support Boot Camp"

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, upgrade

I have a 2009 Mac Pro (MacPro4,1) which, until recently, had both OS X Yosemite and a Boot Camp install of Windows 10 on it.  Shortly after I upgraded to El Capitan, I found that Boot Camp Assistant refused to run, reporting "This Mac does not support Boot Camp".

Furthermore, I am unable to use BootChamp to reboot into Windows, as it reports a cryptic message "Bless failed".

Any ideas what would cause Boot Camp to stop working?

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows? Or, is it that you can not boot to Windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: The latter.  Updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for fixing Boot Camp Assistant was the same as with previous versions of the OS: [reset the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

I found a discussion mentioning a similar problem with an upgrade to Yosemite [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6824446?start=0&tstart=0) that I intiially disregarded as it referenced repairing permissions and running a Disk Verify, neither of which Disk Utility appears to support anymore.

As for BootChamp, [it is no longer supported as of El Capitan](http://kainjow.tumblr.com/post/128933657269/bootchamp-and-el-capitan).  System Integrity Protection prevents it from running.

Comment: You can disable SIP if you want.

Comment: After two years this answer is still useful. I have the same machine.